# Failed to upload Azure Service Fabric package to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I cannot upload an ASF package to a remote Azure Image Store. The process fails using the following script at 53.8% with 0/6 replicated files (0/0% complete).

I cannot also publish to a remote cluster using Visual Studio. As I get the following error:

> WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover

Are there any alternative ways of pushing up an application? The Azure Service Fabric on Azure experience just isn't working for me and I've wasted days on it.

Thanks in advance!

[image]
Powershell deployment script below:

```
# Variables
$endpoint = 'XXX-asf.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com:19000'
$privateThumbprint = 'XXX'
$publicThumbprint = 'XX'

$projectPath = "C:\dev\asf-network-hops\AsfNetworkHops\AsfNetworkHops\AsfNetworkHops.sfproj"
$projectConfiguration = "Debug"

$packagePath = Resolve-Path "$projectPath\..\pkg\$projectConfiguration"
$applicationTypeName = "AsfNetworkHopsType"
$applicationName = "fabric:/AsfNetworkHops"

$imageStoreConnectionString = "fabric:ImageStore"

# Connect
# $conn = Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint $endpoint `
#           -KeepAliveIntervalInSec 10 `
#           -X509Credential -ServerCertThumbprint $privateThumbprint `
#           -FindType FindByThumbprint -FindValue $publicThumbprint `
#           -StoreLocation CurrentUser -StoreName My

$imageStoreConnectionString = ""
$conn =  Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint XXX-asf.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com:19000 `
                            -KeepAliveIntervalInSec 10 `
                            -X509Credential -ServerCertThumbprint XXX`
                            -FindType FindByThumbprint -FindValue XXX`
                            -StoreLocation CurrentUser -StoreName My

if (-not $conn)
{
   $conn
   throw "Connection error!"
}

# Clean, Compile, & Package
 dotnet clean $projectPath /p:Configuration=$projectConfiguration /nologo
 dotnet msbuild $projectPath /t:Package /nologo /p:Platform="x64" /p:Configuration=$projectConfiguration /nologo /p:WarningLevel=1


Write-Host "Uploading package $packagePath"
Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage $packagePath -ImageStoreConnectionString $imageStoreConnectionString -ApplicationPackagePathInImageStore $applicationTypeName -ShowProgress -ShowProgressIntervalMilliseconds 500 -TimeoutSec 1000000 -CompressPackage
```